# How can I add up my selection lists, radios, and checkboxes to total?

Tags: javascript

I need some guidance in how to add my selection list to my total. I am still new to javascript so i did what i could but for some reason, i cannot figure out how to add the selection list to my total. the textboxes with 0.00 are there for me to see if the radios, checkboxes and selection are adding up properly.

```js
``
`
function customerInfo(cName){
 var dinerName = document.getElementById(cName).value;
 document.getElementById('cust_name').innerHTML = dinerName;
}
// format val to n number of decimal places
function formatDecimal(val, n) {
n = n || 2;
var str = "" + Math.round ( parseFloat(val) * Math.pow(10, n) );
while (str.length <= n) {
    str = "0" + str;
}
var pt = str.length - n;
return str.slice(0,pt) + "." + str.slice(pt);
}

function getRadioVal(form, name) {
var radios = form.elements[name];
var val;

for (var i=0, len=radios.length; i<len; i++) {
    if ( radios[i].checked == true ) {
        val = radios[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
return val;
}

function getToppingsTotal(e) {
var form = this.form;
var val = parseFloat( form.elements['tops_tot'].value );

if ( this.checked == true ) {
    val += parseFloat(this.value);
} else {
    val -= parseFloat(this.value);
}

form.elements['tops_tot'].value = formatDecimal(val);
updatePizzaTotal(form);
}

function getSizePrice(e) {
this.form.elements['sz_tot'].value = parseFloat( this.value );
updatePizzaTotal(this.form);
}

function getDeliveryPrice(e){
 selectElement = document.querySelector('#pick_delivery'); 
 output = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value; 
 console.log(output);
}

function updatePizzaTotal(form) {
var sz_tot = parseFloat( form.elements['sz_tot'].value );
var tops_tot = parseFloat( form.elements['tops_tot'].value );
form.elements['total'].value = formatDecimal( sz_tot + tops_tot );
}
// removes from global namespace
(function() {

var form = document.getElementById('pizzaForm');

var el = document.getElementById('pizza_toppings');
 
// input in toppings container element
var tops = el.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i=0, len=tops.length; i<len; i++) {
    if ( tops[i].type === 'checkbox' ) {
        tops[i].onclick = getToppingsTotal;
    }
}
 
var sz = form.elements['size'];

for (var i=0, len=sz.length; i<len; i++) {
    sz[i].onclick = getSizePrice;
}

// set sz_tot to value of selected
form.elements['sz_tot'].value = formatDecimal( parseFloat( getRadioVal(form, 'size') ) );
 
updatePizzaTotal(form);
})(); // end remove from global namespace and invoke
```

````html
<form name="pizzaOrder" method="post" id="pizzaForm" enctype="text/plain">
  <fieldset style="width: 60%;">
    <legend>Create Your Pizza</legend>
    <h3>Customer's Name:</h3>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name" value="First and Last Name" size="30" value="" />
      <input type="button" onclick="customerInfo('client_name')" value="Enter"></button>
    </p>
    <h3>Pick Your Size:</h3>
    <p>
      <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="8" /> Small</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="10" /> Medium</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="12" /> Large</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="14" checked/> Extra Large</label>
      <input type="text" name="sz_tot" value="0.00" />
    </p>
    <h3>Pick Your Toppings</h3>
    <p id="pizza_toppings">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="Pineapple" value="1.50" /> Pineapple</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="Onions" value="1.50" /> Onions </label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="Ham" value="1.50" /> Ham</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="Sausage" value="1.50" /> Sausage</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="Pepperoni" value="1.50" /> Pepperoni</label>
      <input type="text" name="tops_tot" value="0.00" />
    </p>
    <h3>Delivery Or Pick Up</h3>
    <p>
      <select class="delivery" id="pick_delivery" size="2">
        <option value="0">Pick Up: Free</option>
        <option value="2">Delivery: $2</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" onclick="getDeliveryPrice()" id="delivery_pick" value="enter" /></button>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Total: $ <input type="text" name="total" class="num" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="result.php" target="_blank"><input type="button" value="Confirm" /></a>
      <a href="cancel.php" target="_blank"><input type="button" value="Cancel"></a>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div>
  <h2>Your Order:</h2>
  <p>
    <h4>Your Name: <span id="cust_name">&nbsp;</span></h4>
    <h4>Your Pizza Size:</h4>
    <h4>Toppings Selected:</h4>
  </p>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>```
````

On the bottom of the page the results should look similar to this:

```
Your Name: Pam Love
Pizza Size Selected: Extra Large
Toppings Selected: Bacon, Pineapple, Ham    
Total:  20.50
```

When clicked on confirm order, the onclick button should redirect the page to a new tab that says:

```
Your order will be ready in 20 minutes.
```

or if cancelled then the user clicks the cancel button also redirected to a new tab:

```
Your order is cancelled.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use some css selectors to accomplish most of this.

Here is how you can get your selected size:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="size"]:checked').value
```

And here is how you can get the list of toppings:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][name="topping"]:checked')].map((t) => t.value).join(', ')
```

The remaining things should be pretty easy to find using querySelector or getElementById

Comment: I'm sorry where do I input this code? And i have not learned this, can you explain what it does in my program?

Comment: You can put the part for getting the selected topping in the `picktopping` function and the code for getting the selected size in the `pickSize` function. Personally I would do this much differently but that should give you a starting place.